# Metaclass conflict, multiple inheritance, and instance as parent

Tags: python, inheritance, metaclass

I've been messing around with the dark arts of Python and there's something I'd like help understanding. Given a class `Foo`, here's some ways I attempted to inherit from it:

1. `class A(Foo)` — Works, unsurprizingly
2. `class B(Foo())` — works provided `Foo` has an appropriate `__new__` method (which I provided)
3. `class C(Foo(), Foo)` — works, under the same conditions as `B`
4. `class D(Foo, Foo())` — gives the famous metaclass error:

   > Traceback (most recent call last):
   >      File "test.py", line 59, in 
   >           class D(Foo, Foo()):
   >   TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict)
   >   subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases

What exactly is it that causes this conflict? When I inherit from `(Foo(), Foo)` (instance first, class second) it works, but when I inherit from `(Foo, Foo())` (class first, instance second), it doesn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you "inherent from an instance", what you're really doing is a strange way of using a metaclass. Normally, class objects are instances of `type`. In the case of class B above, it inherits from an instance of `Foo`. This is exactly what would happen if you defined a class with `Foo` as its metaclass, and then inherited from that.

So my speculation as to what's happening here is that Python is processing the base classes in reverse MRO order.

Class C works because the first parent class to be processed is `Foo`, whose class is `type`. This means that the metaclass of D must be `type`, or some subclass thereof. Then `Foo()` is processed, whose class is `Foo`, which is a subclass of `type`, so everything's fine.

Class D fails because the first parent class to be processed is `Foo()`, which sets a constraint that D have a metaclass of `Foo` (or subclass). Then `Foo` comes along, whose class `type` is *not* a subclass of `Foo`.

That is a complete guess, but you could try and see if the Python documentation on metaclasses requires when you multiply inherit from two classes with different metaclasses, where the metaclasses involved have a subtype relationship, that you put them in a particular order.

Comment: @Paul MRO is "method resolution order", which is the order in which a class and its parents are checked when looking up methods/attributes. My intuition was just that since methods in the first parent 'override' those in the second, Python would process the second one, then process the first.